# How to set plus two years in daterangepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

I have two daterangepicker, I want to set plus two year as the maxdate for the second daterangepicker based on the value from first daterangepicker. For example if I set the value to "2019-10-10" on the first daterangepicker then the maxdate should be set to the second datepicker as "2021-10-10".

This is what I have tried but not seems to be working

```
      $('.date-select').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        locale: {
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        },
      }).on("input change", function (e) {
        $("#end_date").daterangepicker({ singleDatePicker: true, minDate: -0,dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD', maxDate: "+0D+0M+2Y" });
      });
      $('#end_date').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        locale: {
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        },
      });
    }
  });
```

It shows invalid date. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you referencing the first date input at all. Try fetching it's value, convert it to a Date object, add two years and set it as the new `maxDate` of the `#end_date` input like so:

```
$('#start_date').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
    locale: {
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  },
}).on("input change", function (e) {
  let d = new Date( $('#start_date').val() );
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 2);
  $('#end_date').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true, locale: {format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'}, maxDate: d
  });
});
$('#end_date').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true, locale: {format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'},
});
```

See this [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/buyahif/3/edit?js,output) for a demo.

By the way: you might have your reasons to choose otherwise, but it would be much easier if you don't use two seperate inputs and define `maxSpan` option. That way, you don't have to deal with events at all and the library does the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'OnSelect' event of Datepicker for the same...

```
$("#From_Date").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
    var years = parseInt(2);

    d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + years);

    $('#To_Date').datepicker('setDate', d);

  }
});

$("#To_Date").datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

this is html for it.

```
<input id="From_Date" />

<input id="To_Date" />
```

Comment: It's better to add the example on Stack Overflow directly.